# If F is a finite field, then $F^*$ is cyclic and $F=\Bbb{Z}_p(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha$.

Tags: field-theory

From Galois Theory (Rotman):

> If F is a finite field, then $F^*$ [which is the multiplicative group] is cyclic and $F=\Bbb{Z}_p(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha$.
>
> **Proof** If $|F|=q$, take $\alpha$ to be a primitive (q-1)st root of unity.

I find this proof a bit confusing...

1) How do we know that F has a (q-1)st primitive root of unity, or any root of unity for that matter?

2) How do we know that $F=\Bbb{Z}_p(\alpha)$? I know that every finite field must have an isomorphic copy of $\Bbb{Z}_p$, but I don't understand how a finite field is *equal* $\Bbb{Z}_p(\alpha)$.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is this the entire proof? Doesn't it prove that $F^*$ is cyclic here or somewhere else? I don't have access to this book.

Comment: The _equal_ is to be understood as isomorphic to. For the other questions, the existence of a primitive $(q-1)$-st root of unity $\alpha \in F$, and hence $F = P_F(\alpha)$ (where $P_F$ denotes the prime field of $F$) are immediate consequences of the fact that $F^\ast$ is cyclic. That one may have been proven elsewhere.

Comment: @AymanHourieh Yes this is the entire proof, and yes it does prove that $F^*$ is cyclic somewhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall that every element of $\mathbb{F}_q$ is fixed by the Frobenius map $x\mapsto x^q$. But this means every element satisfies the polynomial equation $x^q-x=0$. If we throw out $0$, consider $x(x^{q-1}-1)=0$ and we get that every non-zero element is a $(q-1)$st root of unity. Conversely, since there are $q-1$ distinct non-zero elements we see that the groups are the same.

So $\mathbb{F}_q^*$ is the group of $(q-1)$st roots of unity which is cyclic and generated by a primitive root of unity. Depending on the author, $\mathbb{F}_q$ is the splitting field of $x^q-x$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$. By the previous part of the argument, if you adjoin a generator for $\mathbb{F}_q^*$, then you get all roots by taking powers. Thus $\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha)=\mathbb{F}_q$.

Comment: You seem to be missing an argument for why such a primitive root exists.

Answer (score 2):

More generally, if $F$ is a field and $G$ a finite subgroup of $F^\times$, then $G$ is cyclic. This follow from the same hint:
With $n=|G|$, we have $g^n=1$ for all $g\in G$, hence all $g\in G$ are roots of the polynomial $X^n-1\in F[X]$. Since there are at most $n$ such roots, the elements of $G$ are *precisely* the $n$ roots of the polynomial $X^n-1$ (of which we didn't even knwo a priori that it splits into linear factors over $F$). Now let $g$ be a root of $X^n-1$, but not of $X^d-1$ for any $d|n$ (there are precisely $\phi(n)>0$ such *primitive* roots, as follows if you show $n=\sum_{d|n}\phi(d)$ e.g. by induction). Then clearly $G=\langle g\rangle$.